# Why Zapier (Office --> Wrike) does not provide fields for start date and end date?

Tags: office365, zapier

[image]I need to sync calendar of Office with Wrike. Wike >> Office works well, but in the template of Office >> Wrike, there is no start date and end date. I do not either see where to add more fields. And it is strange there are couple of fields for attachments. I doubt this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I checked in our system and I see that we've got an open request for this. The Wrike team owns the app, so I'd reach out to them to get them to address the issue. If you write into contact@zapier.com from your Zapier account's email (and reference this question), we can add you to the list of users who want to see this implemented (which helps their team prioritize).

---

As as side note, be careful about doing a 2 way sync with Zapier. That's a good way to end up with an infinite loop. There's more info here: https://zapier.com/help/avoiding-zap-loops/

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!